# lvconvert between different volumegroups -LVM

Tags: server, 18.04, raid, lvm, mdadm

There are 2 lvs which are in the VG Raid.
This two lvs should be an LVM Mirror.
This 2 lvs should be mirrored in another VG called non-Raid.

```
sudo vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 
  Raid       4  16   0 wz--n-  7,27t  2,60t
  non-Raid   4   5   0 wz--n- <3,60t 25,23g
```

Is LVM able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the needed answer here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515203/lvconvert-between-different-volumegroups-lvm

```
sudo lvcreate -L 275GB -n Wichtig Raid
sudo lvcreate -L 275GB -n Wichtig non-Raid
sudo vgcreate Wichtig /dev/Raid/Wichtig /dev/non-Raid/Wichtig
sudo lvcreate -m1 -L 250GB -n Bilder Wichtig
sudo lvcreate -m1 -l 100%FREE -n Wichtige-Daten Wichtig
```

Then i copied the data with dd